# How to define 'p' with ROOT using Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to launch a full stack web application using Python and Flask and inside my server interface/top layer file the ROOT line with 'p' is saying that it is not defined. Is there another set of variables I can assign to it in the same file to solve the problem when attempting to launch in terminal?

I have already tried launching with different versions of Python in terminal and assigning p to path in the code but then it says user isn't defined.

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from os import path

ROOT = path.dirname(p/Users/matthewdeyn/Coffea/app.pyath.relpath((__file__)))

def create_post(name, content):
    con = sql.connect(path.join(ROOT, 'database.db'))
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('insert into posts (name, content) values(?, ?)', (name, content))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

def get_posts():
    con = sql.connect(path.join(ROOT, 'database.db'))
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('select * from posts')
    posts = cur.fetchall()
    return posts
```

Expected results are that the app.py file will be loaded in terminal and I will know where to find it in the browser.

Comment: You're missing some quotes there

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to set ROOT to in words? Something like "`p/Users/matthewdeyn/Coffea/app` relative to the the current file"?

Comment: Hi, yes I exactly as it is written. I'm not sure where p is accessed also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the directory containing your file, you can use

```
ROOT = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))
```